# Response is not called in Jest test

Tags: testing, jestjs, response

I would like to test this file:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { DocumentObject, ExistingResourceObject, ResourceObject } from 'jsonapi-fractal';
import path from 'path';
import jwt, { Secret } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import fs from 'fs';
import { fetchKey } from '../auth/jwt';

import makeAuthRequest from '../makeAuthRequest';
import getToken from '../getToken';

const authApiPublicKey = path.join(__dirname, '../../assets/keys/auth_api_public_key.cer');

const transformSupplier = (data: ExistingResourceObject) => ({
  id: data.id,
  type: data.type,
  attributes: {
    name: data.attributes.name,
  },
});

const transformResponse = (response: DocumentObject): DocumentObject => {
  if (Array.isArray(response.data)) {
    const transformedData: ResourceObject[] = response.data
  .filter((data) => data.attributes.active)
  .map((data: ExistingResourceObject) => transformSupplier(data));

    return {
      data: transformedData,
    };
  }

  return {
    data: transformSupplier(response.data as ExistingResourceObject),
  };
};

function verifyToken(token: string) {
  return (
    Promise.resolve(token)
      // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
      .then((t) => {
        try {
          jwt.decode(t, { complete: true }) as { payload: jwt.JwtPayload };
        } catch (error) {
          return Promise.resolve(false);
        }
      })
      .then((decodedToken) => {
    if (decodedToken.payload.kid) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
          return fetchKey(decodedToken.payload.kid) as Promise<Secret>;
        }
        return fs.readFileSync(authApiPublicKey);
      })
      .then((key: Secret | Buffer) => {
        try {
          return jwt.verify(token, key, {
            algorithms: ['RS256'],
          });
        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error('Error verifying the token');
        }
      })
      .then((payload: jwt.JwtPayload) => {
        if (!payload || !payload.exp || !payload.email) {
          throw new Error('Payload was malformed');
        }
        return payload;
      })
      .catch((err: string) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      })
  );
}

export default async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  const token: string = getToken(request);

  try {
    const payload = await verifyToken(token);
    if (!payload) {
      response.status(401).send('Not authenticated for this endpoint');
    } else {
      await makeAuthRequest(
        request,
        response,
        () => ({
          endpointKey: 'affiliate.suppliers',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
          },
          gzip: true,
        }),
        transformResponse,
      );

      response.end();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(401).send('Not authenticated for this endpoint');
  }
};
```

The point of this file is to validate/verify JWT token before making the `makeAuthRequest`. The code works as expected however one test (the first one) is failing

```
Supplier › should reply with list of suppliers

expect(jsonp mock default).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: ObjectContaining {"data": [{"attributes": {"active": true, "name": "Abbycar"}, "id": "430", "type": "suppliers"}]}

Number of calls: 0

  33 |
  34 |     await suppliers(req, res);
> 35 |     expect(res.jsonp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
     |                       ^
  36 |       expect.objectContaining(supplierMock.transformedResponse),
  37 |     );
  38 |   });

  at Object.toHaveBeenCalledWith (tests/server/endpoints/supplier/supplier.test.ts:35:23
```

This is test file:

```
 import { getMockReq, getMockRes } from '@jest-mock/express';
 import nock from 'nock';

 import suppliers from '../../../../src/endpoints/suppliers';
 import supplierMock from '../../mocks/supplier/supplier.response';

 const { res, mockClear } = getMockRes();

 describe('Supplier', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
     mockClear();
   });

   it('should reply with list of suppliers', async () => {
     const req = getMockReq({
       headers: {
         host: 'localhost',
         authorization:
           'Bearer this.is.valid',
       },
       IS_BRIDGE: 'true',
     });

     nock('http://localhost:8001')
       .get(`/api/suppliers`)
       .matchHeader(
         'authorization',
         'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.FPjPxTBrIh2jJUNfVSitkKsl2CRpBWhHhEx-rQXuTreIqb9eQ9Sz4cReNpfHro0EKvNjS_uVA_WbtTWoyudzgqZJH-BteAyorzp92tvOurLhY0Drfn1qMTh80AK1fjYlpeYEC3gq9wz3ddBxcpCm3wfsm4hBwBPsFJKV8_c6mD7Qunjw9N4LCsjx-tS5SQzabrf9rBHSKOiJk4VyhSK467slEYap02SzmktnbTNCfEK6qAKv3XWynvnLzXXKTjRrgV-RJS1lcow0wQ_wM7Xcas-JKrCd535rW9MzOEay4kvETLFjnKK3ZmhwW-lhgIF_sQ0tD0FkYcAIznmjLBcfPg',
  )
  .matchHeader('content-type', 'application/vnd.api+json')
  .matchHeader('accept', 'application/vnd.api+json')
  .reply(200, supplierMock.apiResponse);

    await suppliers(req, res);
    expect(res.jsonp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining(supplierMock.transformedResponse),
    );
  });

  it('should reply with 401 error, if not authenticated', async () => {
    const req = getMockReq({
      headers: {
        host: 'localhost',
        authorization: 'no.valid.token',
      },
      IS_BRIDGE: 'true',
    });

    await suppliers(req, res);

    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);
    expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Not authenticated for this endpoint');
  });
});
```

Lets assume that the 'Bearer this.is.valid' is valid token. The second test is green because is caught in catch block and returned with 401. I would also like to get rid of try catch block, but that makes both tests red.

I tried mocking verifyToken and other function but still seems to not work.